# Is it possible to use a URL to access a template and JSON result - Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Is it possible to use a URL to access a template and JSON result - Django?

The idea is not to generate unnecessary url.

Something like that:

```
> path(r'cnpj', CNPJ.as_view(), name='cnpj'),
> path(r'cnpj', CNPJ_JSON.as_view(), name='cnpj_json'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a `query_param` along with your request and evaluate it on your view in order to return the desired content:

```
...cnpj/?desired_format=json
```

And in your view:

```
class CNPJ(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        if request.query_params['desired_format'] == 'json':
            return json
        else:
            render html
```